# How to draw a texture without perspective on a plane, using OpenGL Shaders?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I am attempting to draw a 2d character in a 3d environment. I am using a plane facing at the camera. This gives me the correct result *only if there is no depth intersection with walls*. Turning depth testing off is not the answer, because the plane still needs to be behind other walls, doors, and objects.

[image: A.) Plane facing camera - Plane intersects with wall and objects]

I then made the plane perpendicular which gives me the desired result for depth test intersection. However now the 2d character is deformed because of the perspective, and appears to give him a big head and/or shorter body. Not the result I am after.

[image: B.) Plane is perpendicular - Perspective deforms 2d character]

Ideally I want to be able to draw a plane perpendicular to use the desired depth testing intersecting, and use a shader to draw the texture without perspective (and to scale). This maintains the depth test intersecting of the plane (for walls, doors, objects, etc.) and gives me the correct proportions for the 2d character.

[image: C.) Plane is perpendicular - Texture is drawn without perspective]

**Updated**

Maybe another approach is to to use stencils? Ideally not using them would be good.

- Enable stencil testing and set test function and operations to write 1s to all stencils.
- Draw plane perpendicular.
- Set stencil function to pass if stencil value equals 1.
- Draw 2d character facing camera.
- Disable stencil testing.

**Updated**

Maybe drawn as a flat reflection on the plane without using normals? Like a cube reflection, or spherical reflection, but only flat. Any ideas?

Comment: What you have drawn in C just doesn't make sense. There is no trapezoidal distortion that is affine at the same time. You could find some sub-parallelogram in there for which the mapping could be defined in principle. But it's a moot point. There is no clipping at all in A, just the depth test, which can be disabled.

Comment: If you don't want perspective correction, just draw it as a 2D sprite. You must however calculate the correct *scaling* by querying the distance of the character from the camera ("depth" value)

Comment: @meowgoesrhedog, yes this would be ideal. Calculating scale would be easy enough, however I do want the depth testing of the plane.

Comment: @derhass, clipping doesn't just relate to the view frustum clipping. By definition it means "a small piece trimmed from something". I have updated my question to avoid confusion in the future. Yes, I have tried it as a parallelogram on the given setup, but it causes distortion of its own. Perhaps if it was subdivided there would be less obvious distorting from your approach. However, this is not my question.

Comment: Clipping is well-defined in the context of OpenGL. Fragments failing the depth test isn't clipping.

Comment: @derhass if your unable to offer a solution please leave the comments to those who can, thank you

Comment: I believe @derhass is trying to correct your technical terminology; and while his comment doesn't necessarily help you solve the problem, using inaccurate terms can sometimes cause confusion. Anyway, if you want to depth test the sprite you must draw it in-plane as you would normally, *but* you can scale the top and bottom edges of the sprite quad to correct for perspective distortion, using their camera-space depth values (this is assuming that the sprite faces the camera)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think derhass mentioned there is no trapezoidal distortion that is affine at the same time. I have tried as you mentioned, however a new distortion arises. I do think this is a novel ideal, maybe it requires a plane divided into a 4x4 or 8x8 mesh, as I mentioned, to combat the distortion. But, as the question asks. I am after a shader.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use your solution from A) but change your Z value (used for depth test) to be in a better position.

So at the end of your vertex shader you will have something like this:

```
gl_Position = projModelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Which is converting your 3d position to a screen space position. Changing gl_Position.z will change the value used to depth test with. You want this value slightly closer to the camera in this situation.

It might end up being complicated to get this value correct but assuming your model matrix is the point at the bottom middle of your sprite then zeroing your world space Z,X and keeping just the Y axis of each vert, will give you a decent position to be z tested with.

```
gl_Position = projModelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
gl_Position.z = projModelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, position, 0.0, 1.0);
```

*Caveats: Not tested, haven't touched glsl in a while, just typing this off the top of my head.

Good Luck!

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, essentially you are saying to pull the gl_Position.z forward to the camera to recreate the plane I desired to use for depth testing? 

I attempted just that with the following code:
`gl_Position = projModelViewMatrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
gl_Position.z = (projModelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, position.y, position.y * 0.39283710065919303, 1.0)).z;`

With the magic number being calculated by:
`a = camera angle
h = height of plane
1 / (cos(a) * h * 2)`

This works perfectly when the plane is centered vertically on the screen...

Comment: ...however, if the plane is not centered vertically on screen, i.e. perhaps at the bottom of the screen behind a wall, then the plane intersects the wall as if it was leaning forward toward the camera. Which makes sense even a flat plane facing the camera will be closer in the center than the edges. Now for being a little too wishful perhaps, is there anyway around that?